# Issue in deploying Angular app in firebase hosting using bitbucket pipelines

Tags: javascript, angular, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

i am deploying angular app ver.8 in firebase hosting by using bitbucket pipelines but getting some erros in running pipelines.
I made some changes in some file,check the following:
**e2e: protractor.conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
...,
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--headless', '--no-sandbox']
    }
  }
...}
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
...,
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive"
}
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
...,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    }
})
}
```

**bibucket-pipelines.yml**

```
image: node:10.16.3
pipelines:
   branches:
      master: #master branch
      - step:
         deployment: production
         caches:
         - node
         script:
         - npm install
         - npm install -g @angular/cli
         - npm install -g firebase-tools 
         - ng build --prod
         - ls -laR ./dist #recursively list directories
         - firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN --project your-prod-firebase-projectname --non-interactive
      develop: # develop branch 
      - step: 
         deployment: test
         caches:
         - node
         script:
         - npm install
         - npm install -g @angular/cli
         - npm install -g firebase-tools 
         - ng build
         - ls -laR ./dist #recursively list directories
         - firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN --project your-test-firebase-projectname --non-interactive
```

And I have added the firebase token in bitbucket pipelines variable but error showing:

```
    1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<app-header></app-header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <section>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to run "**ng serve --prod**" on your local? You will probably be able to get more information about this error because it doesn't look like a Bitbucket error but more like an Angular error. You can also put your Firebase credentials in Bitbucket, I made an article about that : [Build a Bitbucket CI/CD with Angular and Firebase](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/build-a-ci-cd-with-bitbucket-angular-and-firebase-7731ae6af49f)